# WCF transfers null for complex types

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a bunch of 3rd party contracts that are only XmlSerializable, and cannot be changed, however I would need to transfer them through a WCF channel. They are not decorated with DataContract / DataMember attributes, and I have no control over that.

Example:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05", IsNullable=true)]
public partial class HotelReservationsType
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("HotelReservation")]
    public HotelReservationsTypeHotelReservation[] HotelReservation
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hotelReservationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hotelReservationField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("RoutingHop", IsNullable=false)]
    public RoutingHopTypeRoutingHop[] RoutingHops
    {
        get
        {
            return this.routingHopsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.routingHopsField = value;
        }
    }

    ...
```

I've created a very basic WCF Service (mostly generated by Visual Studio) and a Client that was also generated by VS with the Add Service Reference function. The above mentioned contracts are in a separate assembly that both projects reference, and in the client known types are selected to be re-used.

According to this (as much as I understand it): [WCF Serializable Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/serializable-types) WCF should be able to transfer objects of the above type, but all I get are nulls for all the members of the type.

[image]

Why is my object containing nulls only, what am I doing wrong?
Are DataContract / DataMember  decorations a must have? How are we supposed to use 3rd party, non-WCF contracts then?